# How to join two ranges in excel to use in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple ranges/arrays that I want to join to use in the PERCENTILE() function.

Here is a (simplified) data to explain the issue:

[image: Sample Data]

Here is the method I used to find the average: `{=AVERAGE(IF(A3:A8="HR",B3:B8),IF(C3:C8="HR",D3:D8),IF(E3:E8="HR",F3:F8))}`

Since you need to specify the Percentile in the PERCENTILE() formula, you can't just list the ranges back to back, unfortunately.

This is what I've tried (which returns #VALUE):

```
{=PERCENTILE((IF(A3:A8="HR",B3:B8),IF(C3:C8="HR",D3:D8),IF(E3:E8="HR",F3:F8)),0.5)}
```

How can I combine those ranges/arrays that are returned from the IF() statements into one range I can use in any formula?

Note: The actual data set is very large, so helper columns are not feasible if the number of helper columns needed grows with the number of columns in the data set.

Answer (score 1):

The `AGGREGATE` function provides functionality for calculating percentiles with arrays:

```
=AGGREGATE(16,6,1/1/(A3:F8="HR")*(B3:G8),0.5)
```

As per screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the actual data set has multiple columns in between each Function column, so doing the multiplication like this wouldn't quite work.

Comment: Hi @user7758051, have you tried it? The number of columns in the range shouldn’t matter... only that the relevant pay columns are one column to the right of the function columns

Comment: Hi @callumDA, To be more specific the columns of the data are as follows: Function USA, Function EMEA, Function Global, Pay Element 1 USA, Pay Element 2 USA, Pay Element 3 USA, Pay Element 1 EMEA, Pay Element 2 EMEA, Pay Element 3 EMEA, Pay Element 1 Global, Pay Element 2 Global, Pay Element 3 Global - Sorry for the confusion; I wasn't thinking about answers that would rely on the relative position of the data.